# Create a grid for memory game

Tags: html, css, css-grid, tailwind-css

How would I create a grid that has this layout?

[image]

I tried something like this but obviously it's not working

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "i i i" "i i i" "i i i" ". i ."
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inside">Hello</div>
  <div class="inside">Hello</div>
  <div class="inside">Hello</div>
  <div class="inside">Hello</div>
  <div class="inside">Hello</div>
  <div class="inside">Hello</div>
</div>
```

I thought if I target the second to last card and create the space that way but can't figure out how to target each card to put in a separate grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `grid-column` property to position each grid item.

```css
.grid-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#last-item-1 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;    /* Start from column-line 2 and end at 3 */
}

#last-item-2 {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;    /* Start from column-line 3 and end at 4 */
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" id="last-item-1"></div>
  <div class="grid-item" id="last-item-2"></div>
</div>
```

You can go through this guide on [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have constraints on the width of the columns, doing this with `flexbox` is easier. Using the `grid` module is tricky to handle the latest child due to its "table-like" behavior, while with flex, you can do it with this:

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div > div {
    background-color: hotpink;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>01</div>
  <div>02</div>
  <div>03</div>
  <div>04</div>
  <div>05</div>
  <div>06</div>
  <div>07</div>
  <div>08</div>
  <div>09</div>
  <div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: ideally I would like to continue using grid but this could be a solution. Thanks

Comment: This will probably be the solution Ill do in the long run to make it reusable.